# Service 'org.kde.kaccessibleapp' does not exist

Tags: gnome, kde, services, gnome-shell

I got this error in `~/.xsession-errors`,

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
Service 'org.kde.kaccessibleapp' does not exist.
```

There is no `kaccessible` in `/usr/lib/kde4/libexec`. I tried to install by `sudo apt-get install kaccessible`, but

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kaccessible : Depends: kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```